# Activity to Fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have 3 android activities and one of them has a surfaceview used to preview the camera. When I swipe right on this activity, an intent is launched and a swipe animation occurs and the other activity is launched. A similar thing happens when I swipe to the left. However, do to the live preview of the camera in the central activity, this is quite laggy and slow, and the screen turns white first before the other activity is launched. To improve this process, I am considering converting the three activities into fragments and using the ViewPager concept to implement these sliding transitions. Is the process of converting the activities to fragments something trivial or is it something that requires a lot of effort which wouldn't be justifiable in this case?

Comment: Try using ViewPager with FragmentStatePagerAdapter,It will work smoothly

Comment: Yes I know but my question is about the process of converting the activities into fragments so that I can do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its quite easy to do. You just have to copy paste your activity view building code to the Fragment, everything stays the same. I would think the effort is just 2 hours to refactor it, its worth it.
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html